# configuration of Eclipse (C++ version) for running SQLite?

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, sqlite

I need to run C++ code via eclipse which has SQlite. I can run it via terminal with typing g++ test.cpp -lsqlite3 . but how can I run it via Eclipse? how should pur the command "-lsqlite3" in its configuration? thanks

this is the begging of the code

```
#include <sqlite3.h> #include <stdlib.h> #include <string.h> // g++ test.cpp -lsqlite3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never written any code in C++ in eclipse. But I've written a lot of java code in eclipse. You can set program arguments for a program like this:
`Menu -> Run -> Run Configurations -> select your application -> click "Arguments" tab on the right -> specify your arguments`.

Please ignore my answer if this is not the case for C++ development in eclipse.